# VBA: Use .Find method to find the first and second value occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I have these columns where the **column headers** are strings followed by random numbers.
I would like to change the first and second occurrence to a specific string. The columns can be in a random order but lower number (or no number) qualifies as a first occurrence.

Input:

| name | date2 | place33 | name2 | date14 | place666 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Output:

| Transfer.name | Transfer.date | Transfer.place | Sender.name | Sender.date | Sender.place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I hoped that the property `SearchOrder=xlnext` helps to identify the first value, but I was wrong.

The rule is that even though the column is missing, the first occurrence from left would be flagged as `Transfer.`.

I tried variety of ways with the option `LookAt:=xlPart` in combination with `*` wildcards to no avail.

The code I used is:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("name", "date", "place", "name*", "date*", "place*")
rplcList = Array("Transfer.name", "Transfer.date", "Transfer.place",_
 "Sender.name", "Sender.date", "Sender.place")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
On Error GoTo NextList:
        Worksheets("Header").Rows(1).Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
'LookAt:= xlPart
Next x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach where you start by collecting all of the headers of interest, grouped according to search term.

Then sort each term's cells according to the numeric suffix (if any) and relabel the first item(s) in the sorted collection.

```vba
Sub RelabelHeaders()

    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim c As Range, e
    Dim dict, k, arr, tmp, col As Collection
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    fndList = Array("name", "date", "place")
    
    'collect all candidate headers: one collection per search term
    For Each c In Worksheets("Header").Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each e In fndList
            'exact match or match+digit[s] (assumes one digit is followed by nothing or by other digits..)
            If c.Value = e Or c.Value Like e & "#*" Then
                If Not dict.exists(e) Then Set dict(e) = New Collection
                dict(e).Add c
                Exit For
            End If
        Next e
    Next c
    
    'loop keys, sort collection and relabel
    For Each k In dict
        Set col = dict(k)
        SortCells col, k
        col(1).Value = "Transfer." & k
        If col.Count > 1 Then col(2).Value = "Sender." & k
    Next k
End Sub

'sort a collection of cells ascending, according to the numeric part(if any)
' remaining after removing `root` from the value
Sub SortCells(col As Collection, root)
    Dim num As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Temp As Range, v1, v2
    num = col.Count
    For i = 1 To num - 1
        For j = i + 1 To num
            'compare based on numeric part only
            v1 = NumberOnly(col(i).Value, root)
            v2 = NumberOnly(col(j).Value, root)
            If v1 > v2 Then
                Set Temp = col(j)
                col.Remove j
                col.Add Temp, , i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

'extract number from cell value (return 0 if no numerix suffix)
Function NumberOnly(v, root)
    v = Replace(v, root, "")
    If Len(v) = 0 Then v = 0
    NumberOnly = CLng(v)
End Function
```

Comment: Great, works even **when the list searches for a header that is not there at all**. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the first thing you have to do is to extract the **numerical portion** of the string as follow (code only for integer number!):

```
Function Extract_Number_from_Text(Phrase As String) As Double
Dim Length_of_String As Integer
Dim Current_Pos As Integer
Dim Temp As String
Length_of_String = Len(Phrase)
Temp = ""
For Current_Pos = 1 To Length_of_String
If (IsNumeric(Mid(Phrase, Current_Pos, 1))) = True Then
    Temp = Temp & Mid(Phrase, Current_Pos, 1)
 End If
Next Current_Pos
If Len(Temp) = 0 Then
    Extract_Number_from_Text = 0
Else
    Extract_Number_from_Text = CDbl(Temp)
End If
End Function
```

After that you have simply to **sort the outputs** of the  `Extract_Number_from_Text`.

In my opinion the `find`-way is not so elegant and can lead to errors.